# object is added to the database without session.commit()

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I run into a weird issue using `SQLAlchemy` in my `Flask API` application, an object is inserted into the database even though the commit instruction is commented:

```
try:
  new_project = model.Projects(project_name, project_desc)
  session.add(new_project)
  session.flush()
  session.refresh(new_project)
  # session.commit()
  response = 'OK'
  return response
except Exception as e:
    logging.error("ERROR :"+str(e))  
    session.rollback()
    response = 'ERROR'
    session.close()
    return response
```

any explications ?

**EDIT:**

here is the class Projects:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()
class Projects(Base, DictSerializable):
    __tablename__ = 'projects'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    description = Column(String)


    def __init__(self, name, description=None):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
```

Comment: What is the purpose of refresh just after flush?

Comment: so that I can get the value of `new_project.id`

Comment: I'd like to see the code for the Projects class. If you didn't write it, it can have a commit command in the `__init__` constructor function of the object which would commit the object on creation. Sometimes you can even inherit from a class that does this without realizing it. I've seen this behavior in some Flask "quickstart" projects on github that many people fork from.

Comment: @DanSafee Kindly see the updated question

Comment: I'm not sure I know the answer, but you do have issues with your code. `flush()` occurs automatically with `commit()` so there is no need to call that. `refresh()` is used to send an SQL query to the database to grab updates to that object. Why would you want to query and update something from the database at a point where you have not actually commited it yet?

Comment: @DanSafee as he mentioned he needs updated Id which he might use to query or something for which we do not need to commit, a refresh will do the job in fetching the id.

Comment: By "committed" do you mean that the row is persisted in the database, or that you can observe it from for example phpMyAdmin while your transaction is in progress? The flush sends changes held in the `Session` to the DB, and they can be visible to other queries, if they use a low enough isolation level. This lacks a [mcve]; perhaps your code is executed in a context that commits, if no exeption is raised. Maybe you use the same session later without rolling back in between. The list goes on.

Comment: By committed I mean, the object is inserted in the database and it has a row in the table. I don't know how to explain it more. I'll edit my question to show more of the code

Comment: A row may be inserted and visible to other queries without being committed yet. It is not quite usual to use READ UNCOMMITTED though.

Comment: I need to read uncommitted so that I can rollback if anything goes wrong. for example I can't insert a flight in the database if the seat is unavailable, so I need the ID of the flight before any commit to book the seat, then if everything goes right, I commit everything. that's just an example.

Comment: Where is `session` defined and how? From using names such as `response` and that other question of yours with identical code it seems you're in a Flask request context. Are you sure you close the session between requests? The scenario that you let the transaction "leak" from request to request, until it commits somewhere seems likely. Also, proper locking (SELECT ... FOR UPDATE, etc.) is the answer to booking use cases, not read uncommitted, if I understood you correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You `session` has probably been created with `autocommit=True` flag. See where the object is created and change that.

Comment: I did that : `_SessionFactory = sessionmaker(bind=engine, autocommit=False, autoflush=True)` but it didn't change anything

Comment: @do you actually see your new data *in the database itself*?? or just from the python code?

Comment: I see it in phpMyAdmin, the database itself

Comment: Also, the default autocommit value in sqlAlchemy is `False`